# monitoring availability of publicly accessible distribution lists

Tags: exchange, monitoring, smtp

I have an unusual request from management: to set up monitoring of public-facing email addresses that resolve to distribution lists(groups).

We are using Exchange 2010 to host these lists/groups. I assume the first step would be to create a test account/mailbox and add it to the groups in question. But what tool or service could I use to:
A) Send a test message
B) Check the mailbox for its reception

Any way this is done, the end users on the list are going to be getting test messages.

Has anyone ever done anything like this?

Comment: Why would this be necessary? Have there been issue with delivery in the past?

Comment: A Distribution Group is available if the Exchange server is available. You should be monitoring the server, not the DG.

Comment: The funny thing about email... End users are the best form of monitoring. They'll *definitely* let you know if something is awry.

Answer (score 0):

> But what tool or service could I use to: A) Send a test message B)
>   Check the mailbox for its reception - OP

This is one of those scenarios when I wish I'd keep a test Exchange VM around after we plunged into O365.

But I digress, Joeqwerty or Ewwhite can remind me if I'm wrong in any of this...

Set up message tracking logs: http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-message-tracking/ -- see there...read it, learn it, do it.

1. Send a test message from Gmail to the distro list's SMTP address
2. Open the Message Tracking Log Explorer in the EMC
3. set the sending and recipient SMTP addresses based on your test email in step #1
4. In the results you should see the flow of the email including DELIVERY results

EDIT: I should also state that if you use EDGE servers or a 3rd party hosted SMTP gateway, Ironmail/Ironport or another phy gateway, then you should consider querying them as well, especially if you don't even see it in the Exchange message tracking logs.  But the Exchange logs should suffice.